# confused by netstat result

Tags: ssh, netstat

I ssh to my ubuntu server and run `sudo netstat -a -p` and I get this:

```
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-25-123.us:ssh mailDOTjjtoursDOTcom:54531  ESTABLISHED 1516/sshd: ubuntu [
```

And when I use my other ssh client, it shows another `jjtoursDOTcom` in there.

I use putty and bitvise.

Why does it show that domain name?
(I replaced dots . with DOT in domain names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netstat does a reverse DNS lookup to display a hostname instead of an IP. You can disable reverse DNS lookup with the `-n` option.

Try this:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp
```

Comment: By any chance do you know how does `netstat` guesses the name there?

Comment: As i said, it does a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). The problem is, that multiple domain names can point to a single IP. So it is possible, that you get an hostname which you do not expect. Hope that explains it a bit.